# Decompile obfuscated dll

Tags: c++, dll

I have to decompile obfuscated dll which was written in Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0 DLL?
How can I do that? I have tried so many software .Net Reflector,JetBrains dotPeeks but they all seems useless :(

Comment: Decompiling C++ is hard, decompiling obfuscated C++ is extra hard. Might help if you explained why you needed to decompile it in the first place.

Comment: I have to use its code in my project thats why need decompilation

Comment: Maybe you can just import the functions with `LoadLibrary` instead?

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why your case is just, moral and legal. You're not just trying to steal some code, are you?

Comment: @RemusRusanu Don't forget, morality aside, the laws in Huda's country may be different to yours.

Comment: @RemusRusanu Plenty of valid (and legal) reasons to decompile code. The DMCA, for instance, permits reverse engineering in order to achieve interoperability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to use the functionality of the DLL, use `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` instead to dynamically load the library and obtain function pointers.

You can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) if you need to see what functions the DLL exports (but it would be easier if you just had a header file for it on hand).

Comment: How do I use LoadLibrary & GetProcAddress in C# any idea pls?

Comment: Use `DllImport`. (You never mentioned C# in your post, so I gave you the C++ solution.)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visual C++ compile code into native x86 code (not CLR).
For decompiling native code into c/assembler you should use IDA Pro with the "hexrays" plug-in.

http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml

Comment: That won't decompile the code into anything recognizable as C/++, though (note that OP wants to use the code in a project).

Comment: "you should" - needless normative text. There are alternatives. Also, hardly a recommendation seeing the OP's actual question context